# Non-abbreviated author name in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I write my thesis using biblatex for bibliography (JabRef for bibliography database) and need to cite an author, that don't have first name and last name, but has name and toponymical nickname.

I have a following entry in .bib file:

```
@Book{simeon,
    Title                    = {Vertograd mnogocvetnyj},
    Author                   = {Simeon Polockij,}, 
    Date                     = {1996-2000},
    Location                 = {Koln, Wemar, Wien},
    Publisher                = {Bohlau},
    Year                     = {1996 - 2000},
    Editor                   = {by Anthony Hippisley a. Lydia I.~Sazonova. With a Foreword by Dmitrij S.~Lihačev.},
    Language                 = {english},
    }
```

In JabRef I see the authorname displayed correctly (Simeon Polockij. Vertograd mnogocvetnyj). But when building bibliography the "," in the end of the name is removed, and the authorname is proceeded in a usual way, and I get "Polockij S. Vertograd mnogocvetnyj", what is totally incorrect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 

\usepackage{fontspec}     
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman} 
\setsansfont{Comic Sans MS}                    
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric, bibencoding=utf8,sorting=none,maxcitenames=2,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe_bib.bib}

\begin{document}
I cite one of the main sources of my research here \cite{simeon}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How to force biblatex not to abbreviate the second part of author name, to get something like "Simeon Polockij. Vertograd mnogocvetnyj. Ed. by Anthony Hippisley a. Lydia I. Sazonova. With a Foreword by Dmitrij S. Lihačev. Bohlau, 1996 - 2000

Comment: The comma immediately after "Polockij" in the `author` field is almost certainly a mistake and should be removed. Why does JabRef include the title of the book, "Vertograd mnogocvetnyj", in the `author field`? Can you change that? Have you tried setting the editor field to `Anthony Hippisley and Lydia I. Sazonova`, i.e., removing "by" and changing "a." to "and"? Finally, is it absolutely necessary to list the author of the Foreword in the bibliography?

Comment: `indentfirst` is specified twice in your MWE which is not minimal at all: I guess that the whole part between `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\usepackage{indentfirst}` is useless. + Do you compile your document with XeLaTex?

Comment: Did you tried to add `abbreviate=false` as an option to `biblatex`?

Comment: Thanks for improving my MWE, I'll try to be more accurate next time :) @Clément, abbreviate=false does a different thing: using "editor" instead of "ed.", "pages" instead of "p." etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following .bib file:

```
@Book{simeon,
  Title                    = {Vertograd mnogocvetnyj},
  Author                   = {{Simeon Polockij}},
  Editor                   = {Hippisley, Anthony and Sazonova, Lydia I.},
  Publisher                = {Bohlau},
  Year                     = {1996\,--\,2000},
  Foreword                 = {Lihačev, Dmitrij S.},

  Langid                   = {english},
  Location                 = {Koln, Wemar, Wien}
}
```

Also add `autolang=other` to your biblatex options.

Answer (score 0):

You should not "overprotect" your `author` field. You can just add the `firstinits=false` option to `biblatex`.
Your `bib` file contains *a lot* of errors, I corrected some of them. The biggest is probably providing an interval for a date of publication.

```
% Compile with
% XeLaTex
% Biber
% XeLaTex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric, bibencoding=utf8, firstinits=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@Book{simeon,
Title={Vertograd mnogocvetnyj},
Author={Polockij, Simeon}, 
Date={1996},
Location={Koln, Wemar, Wien},
Publisher={Bohlau},
Year={1996},
Editor={Hippisley, Anthony and Sazonova, Lydia I.},
addendum={With a Foreword by Dmitrij S.~Lihačev},
Language={english},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
I cite one of the main sources of my research here \cite{simeon}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `\,--\,` to specify a range, as proposed by @invece.

Comment: If I understand right, \firstinits=false affects all entries, and this is not what I want (such form of author name is needed only for medieval authors with toponymical nicknames, not for modern ones). So it seems to be easier to "overprotect" the Author field in several cases.

Comment: @yukari It is easier indeed, but I find it a bit inelegant. I must admit I did not pay attention to the subtlety of your question (that it was not a name and a first name, but a nickname).

Comment: Please note `firstinits` has been renamed to `giveninits` since `biblatex` 3.3.